# How do I change the innerHTML of a global style element with cssRule?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This doesn't really require much content as the code itself is self explanatory. However, just have to escape the condition of writing this context. How 
do I update the innerHTML of a style element by changing the cssText of the stylesheet's cssRule?

HTML:

```
<style>
    body {
        background-color: blue;
    }
</style>
```

JS:

```
var style = document.getElementsByTagName('style')[0];

var sheet = style.sheet;

sheet.cssRules[0].style.backgroundColor = 'green'; // body changes to green.

sheet.cssRules[0].cssText;  // returns "body { background-color: green; }"

style.innerHTML;  // returns "body { backgrounds color: blue; }"
```

How do I change the innerHTML of the style along with the cssRule?

Comment: Style tags don't really have an innerHTML in the traditional sense. However, they can be given an id tag in the traditional sense. Therefore a good way to go about it would be to give your style tags an id, and then use that id to modify it's properties.

Comment: An example of the above would look like this: `document.getElementById('styleIdTag').sheet.cssRules[0].style.backgroundColor = 'green'`

Comment: It doesn't make much different. Calling the element by id, classname, tagname or whatsoever is not the actual point. Any of those identifier can find the precise element if specified clearly. The basic point here now is changing the innerHTML of the text after setting the cssRules background color of the captured style element.

Comment: What "text" is in the innerHTML that is not a style definition? I'm confused.

Comment: InnerHTML of the `style` element, not `text` please. Apologies.

Comment: Look at this person's example and see if it helps answer your questions: http://jsfiddle.net/fttS5/1/

Comment: No it doesn't. He's directly editing the innerHTML of the style. The above was just an example of one cssRule. If there were multiple of about 100 cssRules and I need to change only one of them, i cannot rewrite the whole cssRules in a text node and append to the style element just to change one cssRule. certainPerformance does have a better explanation and example but I'm just trying to comprehend with it right now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192544/discussion-between-uchenna-ajah-and-christopher-bennett).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML markup is usually meant to be *markup*, not *dynamically-changing non-markup data*, as you're using it for in the dynamic stylesheet. If you want the `innerHTML` to change, you'll have to collect the new text of all the `cssRules` and explicitly reassign the `innerHTML` of the `style` element.

(similarly, if you reassign a variable inside a script tag, the `innerHTML` of that script tag doesn't change:

```js
let foo = 5;
foo = 7;
console.log(document.currentScript.innerHTML);
```

)

```html
<style data-st="st">
    body {
        background-color: blue;
    }
</style>
<script>

var style = document.querySelector('style[data-st="st"]');
var sheet = style.sheet;

sheet.cssRules[0].style.backgroundColor = 'green';
const newFullText = [...sheet.cssRules]
  .map(({ cssText }) => cssText)
  .join('\n');
style.innerHTML = newFullText;
console.log(style.innerHTML);

</script>
```

Note that you must use `sheet.cssRules` to get a collection of rules; `sheet.cssRule` will evaluate to `undefined`.

Because you're retrieving and inserting *text* into the inside of the style tag, rather than HTML markup, it might be more appropriate to use `textContent` rather than `innerHTML`:

```html
<style data-st="st">
    body {
        background-color: blue;
    }
</style>
<script>

var style = document.querySelector('style[data-st="st"]');
var sheet = style.sheet;

sheet.cssRules[0].style.backgroundColor = 'green';
const newFullText = [...sheet.cssRules]
  .map(({ cssText }) => cssText)
  .join('\n');
style.textContent = newFullText;
console.log(style.textContent);

</script>
```

Comment: Oops! writing cssRule was an error. I'll ammend that now

Comment: Sorry but if I may ask. The 3 dots you added `[...sheet.cssRule]`. Is that an actual code that is a shortcut to the entire cssRules or you're just trying to reduce context and not rewrite the code again. I really haven't come across 3 dots or its use in javascript

Comment: That's [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), and has been in the Javascript specification for quite a few years now. `[...something]` calls the iterator of `something` and puts all items that the iterator returns into an array - basically, it turns an array-like object into an actual array. (I did it here so that I could use `Array.prototype.map` on it)